# c# create graphics in a PDF and rasterize

Tags: c#, visual-studio, pdf

Is there a way to create graphics above a pdf? I am using Visual Studio in C# and I am having mouse event listeners (like MouseDown, MouseMove, etc) that records mouse points and creates lines in between them, the graphics are painted on a picture box. I want to add those graphics above the **OPENED pdf** and rasterize it for update on changes like Foxit Reader does in its measurement:

[image: Look at this image]

But I cant find any reference how to do it, because i tried using iTextSharp and PdfSharp but none of them allow this edition.

Answer (score 0):

First,create graphics to a image of `Bitmap`.

Then,draw image to pdf file by `iTextSharp`.

Comment: can i do it while the pdf file is open?